# 2 Applications/executables in the system (sublime text)

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text, duplicate, duplicate-files

I have installed two sublime through the recommended way:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

but I also ended up installing through a installer after having some problems:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

and then uninstalled the installer

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer 
sudo apt-get purge sublime
sudo apt-get purge subl
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text-installer && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then I did this:

```
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text && sudo apt-get autoremove
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor
```

But still I get this:

[image]

The second result (the one on the right) just open a slot on the launcher and keeps blinking until it just disappears.

How to solve this issue?